# Babel importing files - Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module './channel'

Tags: node.js, babeljs

Im using babel to compile a commonJS file to run in Node.

I have example

```
import channel from './channel'
```

to import a file  (channel.js) from the same folder.

I've tried both ./channel and ./channel.js

This is getting transpiled as

```
var _channel = _interopRequireDefault(require("./channel"));
```

Which results in

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module './channel'
Require stack:
- /home/owner/workspace/client/desktop/bundle.js
- /home/owner/workspace/client/desktop/start.js
```

How can I get 'channel' inside Bundle as a module?

I can't use RollUp because it doesn't handle the AWS-SDK library, so I'm hoping to do the same thing with Babel.

Answer (score -2):

var generalchannel = Client.channels.find(channel.id === 597941292139282434);

```
setInterval(() => {
    generalchannel.send("")

}, 5000);
```

i try to do this but i cant find channel